# Rerendering component to already rendered container doesnt work as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain it to me why rerendered element doesnt apply change to the element state.status property?Is using `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` proper way to do this?I know that the element should not delete itself but this is for presentation.

```js
class CustomModal extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    
      status:this.props.status
    
    }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  

  render(){
   return  <h1 onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me!</h1>
  }
  
  onClick(){
    
    console.log('May i log to console?:' + this.state.status)
    

    this.setState({status:false});
    
    // this is somewhat cumbersome?
    {/* ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container')) */}
    
    // supposed to rerender the element?
    // And the state.status element should be true?
        ReactDOM.render(<CustomModal status={true} />,document.getElementById('container'))
  }

}


      ReactDOM.render(<CustomModal status={true} />,document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with your example? Changing the state, should notify react to call the render function again, you should not render your component manually. Also you pass status={true}, shouldn't you use status={this.state.status} ?

Comment: I am gradually replacing code  to react and in this stage i need to do this.It should be `status={true}` because i wanted to show an example that state of rerendered element didnt even change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The primary API for rendering into the DOM looks like this:
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.render(reactElement, domContainerNode)
> ```
>
> To update the properties of an existing component, you call render
>   again with a new element.
>
> If you are rendering React components within a single-page app, you
>   may need to plug into the app's view lifecycle to ensure your app will
>   invoke unmountComponentAtNode at the appropriate time. React will not
>   automatically clean up a tree. You need to manually call:
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(domContainerNode)
> ```
>
> This is important and often forgotten. Forgetting to call
>   unmountComponentAtNode will cause your app to leak memory. There is no
>   way for us to automatically detect when it is appropriate to do this
>   work. Every system is different.
>
> It is not unique to the DOM. If you want to insert a React Native view
>   in the middle of an existing iOS app you will hit similar issues.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html

Comment: Thanks alot,shame i didnt find it!